# Re-attach Microsoft Edge f12 developer tool

Tags: developer-tools, microsoft-edge

After pressing F12 I moved the developer tool to a new window.  I want to return it to the nested position at the bottom of the browser window; but it is not as simple as with IE 11.  Does anyone know a shortcut or where a button is hiding?

Comment: edge dont even have refresh button on right click what do you expect from it ... its just trash

Answer (score 1):

You can't :[

Its coming back, but as of now its not something that can be done in Edge